# General signal question with regards to expected behavior

Tags: linux, signals, sigpipe

**Scenario 1**

Lets say the following scenario exists.

My program makes a call to a 3rd party library which in turn calls another 3rd party library which turns around and makes OS calls.

```
   MyProgram
        |
   some3rdPartyFunction() ---> 3rd party library
                                 |
                             another3rdPartyFunction()----> another 3rd party library
                                                                      |
                                                                    OS call()
```

**1st Set of Questions:**

- If this OS calls makes a socket call to a closed socket, what happens?
- Is an error returned to the process making the OS call?
- At what    point does the system return a SIGPIPE message?
- Does the SIGPIPE only get sent to the calling function or does the
  SIGPIPE get    propagated all the way up to MyProgram?

**Scenario 2**

I happen to see the following output of a thread dump of a process.

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ...)
rt_sigreturn({mask=[PIPE]})
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, [], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, [], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, [], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, [], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigreturn({mask=[PIPE]})
```

**2nd Set of Questions:**

- Why are so many signal messages being sent?
- Would these be getting sent directly to MyProgram or being propagated
  up from the lower OS call?
- With the variety of signals being sent, how to determine which one is
  actually causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If this OS calls makes a socket call to a closed socket, what happens?*

Well, "closed" can be a bit misleading when talking about file descriptors (which may be closed) and stream sockets (like TCP, which may be partially or fully shut down).  What I think you're asking about is a [`write()` call error](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html) that POSIX documents as:

*[EPIPE] A write was attempted on a socket that is shut down for writing, or is no longer connected. In the latter case, if the socket is of type SOCK_STREAM, a SIGPIPE signal shall also be sent to the thread.*

> Is an error returned to the process making the OS call?

The error is returned to whatever bit of code called `write`, and the signal is generated for the *thread* that ultimately invoked the `write`.

> At what point does the system return a SIGPIPE message?

The SIGPIPE is generated when attempting to write to an unwritable socket or pipe.

> Does the SIGPIPE only get sent to the calling function or does the SIGPIPE get propagated all the way up to MyProgram?

The SIGPIPE is generated for the *calling thread*.  Where it is in its call chain — your program, the 3rd-party library, etc. — is not germane to signal delivery.

> Why are so many signal messages being sent?

None are being sent in what you show.  Most of those calls are about masking and signal disposition, *not* signal generation.  The `rt_sigreturn` calls tell you that [Linux is handling the delivery of a SIGPIPE](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rt_sigreturn.2.html).

> Would these be getting sent directly to MyProgram or being propagated up from the lower OS call?

I don't understand what this means.  The SIGPIPE is generated for a specific thread in your process, whether your code in MyProgram is aware of that thread's existence, or whether the 3rd-party library "secretly" created the thread under the hood.

> With the variety of signals being sent, how to determine which one is actually causing the problem?

There's only one signal generated in what you show, and that is a SIGPIPE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to have to read through it a couple of times and research further to fully comprehend.